# Is it possible to create a type of object from another type of object with the same keys names, but different types of values of them?

Tags: typescript, types

I have function what takes config object and should return another object with the same property names, but different values of them:

```
function generateTextures(config: {
    default?: boolean,
    multiply?: boolean,
    dark?: boolean
} = {default: true, multiply: true, dark: true}) {
    const textures : {[key: string]: []} = {}; // I want this object type have the same properties as config, but with type [] without duplicating all properties

    const textures : { // Like this, but without write keys names again and change types.
        default?: [],
        multiply?: [],
        dark?: []
    } = {};

    do something...

    return textures;
}
```

Is it possible to do? Thanks!

Comment: Consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to demonstrate what you're doing without any typos or unrelated code or unrelated errors (e.g., why is `type` there? do you want `const textures = {...}` or `const textures: {...}`? ).  If I call `generateTextures({})`, what type should `textures` be?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQFVQA8oRNUBnACggWBmQC5EBvAKEUQBNVhsQANlAD8zAEZw4A1NjAAaDogC2g2AAcBAT1GIJUmfMVdsmANY6902WwC+iALytuvfkOZRMIVHOWqYGzXdPb24TUyCvRBsASlZFWjAKKEQ8EjJKB0VOKgB5MQArVGgAOlNUTWoE+mRY7ApEAEFMHE0AHjLNOGAUzTVULsQqhgA+aOLyLhAIVCoszkQqOB9TWPthhbgAbVMAXQdETZ2fOGifFjs6p02AaUQYJA6BqF7+7qHkHeZDqOiAbkVyKRMEhUkDKLY2GwEkkUsQwfVHGgMDg8IQ0uRqOc-mwAPQAKkGCBhoPSFGY7Hmzj4qh03wAPohwDx6BguP9KSohP4tLS9gymbx7qg2XNjGZeYh+WBmUKRXY8TigA) meet your needs?  If so I'll write it up; if not, please add appropriate details to the question.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, bad explanation was, I just need have type of this object with the same keys names, but value of keys must be [] instead of boolean, to not duplicate all type of object with the same keys and change value type of this keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible; you want to be using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), like this:

```
const textures: { [K in keyof typeof config]: [] } = {};
```

Here you are mapping over the keys in the type `typeof config` (which saves you from writing the type out again).  If you examine the type of `textures`, it will be:

```
/* const textures: {
    default?: [] | undefined;
    multiply?: [] | undefined;
    dark?: [] | undefined;
} */
```

as desired. Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQFVQA8oRNUBnACggWBmQC5EBvAKEUQBNVhsQANlAD8zAEZw4A1NjAAaDogC2g2AAcBAT1GIJUmfMVdsmANY6902WwC+iALytuvfkOZRMIVHOWqYGzXdPb24TUyCvRBsASlZFWjAKKEQ8EjJKZhZEAG0AaUQYJFNUTThgFM01VDLEBPpkAF1mbIaoh1YbRXJSTCRUnspbIA)